# Rust: passing array recursively

Tags: arrays, recursion, reference, rust, mutability

I just got started with Rust and I already have mixed feelings.
Take this dummy example, I hope this is self-explanatory:

```
fn set_values(pos: usize, val: u64, array: &mut [u64]) {
    if pos >= array.len() {
        return;
    }
    array[pos] = val;
    set_values(pos+1, val+1, array);
}
```

This works fine by calling:

```
set_values(0, 42, &mut my_array);
```

I totally get the reason behind `&mut` in the first function call, but why the hell during the recursive call I don't have to specify it?

Not only that, if I decide to write `set_values(pos+1, val+1, &mut array);` then the compiler complains and tells me that I have to change the function signature to

```
fn set_values(pos: usize, val: u64, mut array: &mut [u64])
```

Sorry but to me this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when declaring your array, you're probably doing

```
let myarray = Vec::new();
```

to which you call as,

```
set_values(0, 42, &mut my_array);
```

in the above statement, you're making a mutable reference out of your array. because you function expects a mutable reference to an array, well basically the types have to match. simple enough?

within your function the type of array is already known as `&mut [u64]`

so you don't need to make a mutable reference out of it since it's already a mutable reference. :).

Comment: ah got me there,

Comment: Actually I'm just declaring my_array as `let mut my_array: [u64, 10] = [0; 10];` but I think this doesn't change things (right?).

Anyway thank you, now I get the first example, but the second one I pointed out still troubles me, how can just that reduntant `mut` keyword mess the syntax up? What is going on there?

Comment: its desctructuring syntax, since array in the function is already a mutable reference, passing `&mut array` is making a reference to a reference. which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call differs from the first call in that `array` already is a binding to a `&mut [u64]`, so you can just pass it on like you did in the first example.
In the second example you are trying to create a **mutable** reference to `array`, but that binding is declared in the function header as an **immutable** binding to a mutable reference.
This is why the compiler suggests changing `array` into a mutable binding.